# Rotating device while using accelerometer

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, uiinterfaceorientation

I'm using accelerometer in my first Cocos2D game and it work fine, i'm able to move the sprite using the below code however, when i change the orientation from landscapeLeft to landscapeRight, the sprite stops responding to Y coordination, and the sprite goes to the top of the screen and doesn't properly respond... I believe it's because of changing the device orientation, but i'm not sure since i'm pretty new to App Development, any help will be appreciated.

Here is the sample code i'm using...

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{    
    //this determines how sensitive the accelerometer reacts (higher = more sensitive)
    NSUserDefaults *defaulObj = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    float sensitivity = [defaulObj floatForKey:@"Sensitivity"]; //10.0f
    if (!sensitivity) {
        sensitivity = 6;
    }

    // this controls how quickly the velocity decelerates (lower = quicker to change direction)
    float deceleration = 0.4f;
    static float xVal = 0;

    if (!self.isFlag) {
        xVal = -acceleration.x;
        self.isFlag = TRUE;
    }

    playerVelocity.x = playerVelocity.x * deceleration + (xVal + acceleration.x) * sensitivity;
    playerVelocity.y = playerVelocity.y * deceleration + acceleration.y * sensitivity;
    playerVelocity.y = playerVelocity.y*-1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps out, flips Y along your current device orientation.

```
float rotatedY = acceleration.y;
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
rotatedY *= -1;
}
```

then use **rotatedY** insteat of acceleration.y